# Vite outDir outside of the project root

Tags: .htaccess, vuejs2, build, vuejs3, vite

I am building Vue3 project with Vite and I am using Vite [build.outDir](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-outdir) option to build the project outside of the Vue3 app root. This is my project structure, where in the `frontend` folder is located Vue3 application:

```
my-app/
├─ frontend/
├─ public/
│  ├─ dist/
|  ├─ .htaccess
│  ├─ app.php
```

I am trying to build Vue3 project to `my-app/public/dist/` folder and I have achieved that by setting `outDir` in `vite.config.js` to:

```
build: {
  outDir: '../public/dist'
},
```

Like that project is builded in the `dist` folder, but then when I open page source in the browser, relative URL to the builded script is not correct:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.585a031a.css">
```

For example instead of `/assets/index.585a031a.css` should be `/dist/assets/index.585a031a.css`. Because of that I have added another Vite option `base` to be:

```
base: '/dist/',
```

Like that when I go to page source everything works fine, but the problem is that URL of the application is change from `example.com` to `example.com/dist`.

This is my `.htaccess` file, but I think it is not related with `.htaccess`, because I have same settings in Vue2 application with default Vue CLI (Vite is not used):

```
# Disable directory listing
Options -Indexes
# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Sets the base URL for rewrites
RewriteBase /
# Access to domain root should serve dist folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dist/$1 [L]
# If URL doesn't match any static assets it should serve dist folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api/*
RewriteRule . /dist/$1 [L]
# If URL contains api it should serve app.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/*
RewriteRule .* app.php [QSA,L]
```

So, the main problem is how can I still build app in the `public/dist` folder and keep the URL of the application `example.com` instead of `example.com/dist`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `index.html` is placed inside the `dist` folder. So the URL needs to be `example.com/dist` to serve your `index.html`. You can manually move your `index.html` to the `public` folder to see if it will work with the URL `example.com`.

**Solution:** change your config to:

```
{
...
// base: '/dist/', remove base config
build: {
    outDir: '../public', // this line place index.html in the public folder
    assetsDir: './dist', // this line place your assets in the public/dist folder
  }
}
```